# python subtraction of zero ranked arrays

Tags: python, numpy, rank, subtraction

I am attempting to subtract two zero ranked numpy arrays a and b.
I would like a-b to return an error when they are not of the same size.
For example, if shape(a)=[300,] and shape(b)=[450,];
a-b returns an array of shape[300,450]. I would instead like the program to return an error.

Comment: "a-b returns an array of shape[300,450]" No it doesn't. Did you get the shapes of a and b wrong?

Comment: Are you sure you're even talking about zero-rank arrays? A zero-rank array `a` has `a.shape == ()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try this approach:

```
def mySubtract(a, b):
    if a is None or b is None or a.shape != b.shape:
       sys.stderr.write("a and b don't have the same shape!\n")
       raise ValueError("a and b don't have same shape!")
    return a-b
```

I wasn't sure what you meant by "return an error", but if you prefer to just return an invalid result rather than raising a ValueError exception, you could instead just `return None` or `return "a and b don't have the same shape!"`.

Keep in mind that the caller of your routine would need to know what to do with these special error return codes.  So in general exception might be a cleaner approach.

Comment: No need for the `None` checks. Those should just be handled by the `TypeError` you'll get if you try to do math with `None`.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to look into exceptions.  Here is some pseudocode that should point you on the right track:

```
if a.size() != b.size():
    raise Exception("Invalid sizes")
```

Comment: I don't think numpy.array object contains a size() method but it does have a size attribute.  You could use a.size instead of a.size() however I think OP was looking for a.shape rather than a.size